# Cross site login and redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

We've made an asp.net mvc application which has an affiliates program.

Our affiliates want the possibility to let their customers, probably using a background code (not a form) logging in to our application.

After making the login the user is supposed to be redirected to one of our own URLs.

First of all, we need some help and example of how to do this.

Second of all in case it's indeed possible, allowing this is in fact a cross site scripting right? so does it expose us to attacks?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the redirect need to be re-usable for the same account, or is this a one-time transfer, and they will go directly to your site in the future? Also, how much influence do you have over how the affiliate's sites work? Could you get them to tap into a webservice you created?

Comment: The user needs the possibility to log in every now and then from the affiliate site, on which we don't have any influence, to our site. We can't let them tap anything. Just "click to login" or just some link to our application needs to do this. Afterwards they are on our site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple link couldn't do this safely, the only way to redirect is with a GET, and you never want to pass re-usable login information that way

Here is an option for you... provide an external facing controller that functions like a web service. Include at least the following two actions. One to request a new account from your site, passing in whatever information is necessary, and another to serve as a 'remote login.' Both of these Actions should only accept POSTs and require HTTPS. Inside, they should not accept any transfers of data via Query String, look in the POST object (this is encrypted, and thus, safer).

The 'remote login' action should take their username and password as passed by your affiliate (encrypted in the POST object) and verify that it is valid. It should then generate a new random value, a good thing to use is a GUID, and return it. The affiliate then redirects them to your site, passing the GUID in the query string. The GUID serves as their single-use login token (they will need a new GUID to log in next time).

If they don't need a specific account to do stuff on your site, then you could leave out the 'create account' and simply give your affiliate a code that they send the remote login function to confirm that it is them asking for a login.

What your affiliate would have to do (and you could give them this chunk of code in a single piece and say 'put this on your page, and it will work.') for the actual remote login is to make an AJAX call to your site, requesting the GUID for a one-time login. When it receives said GUID, it will then redirect to your site.

This isn't the best option possible...single-sign-on like behaviors are best when both sides work together to keep things secure and invisible to users, but it is workable and reasonably secure.